# bash/shell - grep exact message structure from a big log file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I would like to advise with you about the following.
i have a big log file with several types of messages but i need to grep only the following message type that always looks like:

```
2015-03-05 15:00:05,294 abcdefgddd {
 msgType: abcsefg
gggggg {
  sendingTime: 1425567605270
  xxxx: 
  yyy {
    timestamp: 1425567605211
    zzz: 
    qqq: 
    vvv: 
  }
  yyy {
    timestamp: 1425567605211
    zzz: 
    qqq: 
    vvv: 
  }
  aaa {
    timestamp: 1425567605211
    zzz: 
    qqq: 
    vvv: 
  }
  aaa {
    timestamp: 1425567605211
    zzz: 
    qqq: 
    vvv: 
  }
}
}
```

this the the message structure.
how can i grep ONLY that structure in Linux shell. can use awk/grep/sed or any other suggestions.

Thank you all.

Comment: did you want to grab the whole?

Comment: yes. exactly. that whole message between the boundaries.

Comment: What is the data before and after this section?

Comment: consider it as any data. this is a log file. there are several message while everyone of them start with time stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we do not know the rest of the file, we can only guess.
This `gnu awk` divides data inn to group, separated by year.

```
awk -v RS="^2015" 'NR>1 {print RS$0}' file
```

To get only one single section:

```
awk '/^2015-03-05 15:00:05/ {f=1} /{/ {c++} /}/ {c--} f && c; !c {f=0}' file
```

This will print from date `2015-03-05 15:00:05` until all `{}` is closed.

Comment: but also before and after that message i have other message start with time tamps.

Comment: @Assafbaruch So you need only one block, if so, what is the trigger to take only this section?  See my updated post.

Comment: right in need that block. but it always start with "msgType: abcsefg" and will always end with "}"

Comment: @Assafbaruch So you need one line above trigger?

Comment: no, i need all the lines in the block. exactly as i mentioned in my first message (=

Comment: @Assafbaruch So you need a block of data starting from the date line to last closing  `}`, but only if block contains `msgType: abcsefg`?

Comment: KING!! it work PERFECT. for learning, can you please explain your answer? thank you so much.